# Codova, can I download a file to (root)/Download folder?

Tags: cordova

I'm using Ionic and Cordova, and I want make my user could download a PDF file to their **(root)/Download** folder. For now it saves on application's data folder, but it's hard to get there, it's like deep inside.

For now my code is like this,

```
let destination = `${cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory}my_app/${fileName}`;
```

and I tried with 'externalRootDirectory',

```
let destination = `${cordova.file.externalRootDirectory}Download/${fileName}`;
```

but that doesn't work. I think my app doesn't have a access to the folder.

Also I tried this,

```
window.requestFileSystem(1, 0, (fs: any) => {
    fs.root.getFile('Download/test.pdf', { create: true, exclusive: false }, (fileEntry: any) => {
        this.$cordovaFile.writeFile('Download/test.pdf', media.src, 'TEST');
    });
});
```

But the **fs** points to the application's data folder. not the Download folder right under the root. Is that possible to access the Download folder that under the root directory?

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: I'm using Ionic and angular1.4

Comment: I don't know how to write in angular.But when you write `let destination=cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"/Download/"+yourFileName;` in JavaScript it will work

Comment: It will save the file in download folder of internal memory

Comment: @Homen I tried but I got this error, "/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: Are you using android marshmallow?Means what device you are using for testing?

Comment: Now I'm testing with android v.6 (Samsung galaxy)

Comment: For testing purpose go to settings and app manager.Then go to your app and go to permissions.And check storage permission is there or not

Comment: If not , enable storage permission and try again

Comment: Wow yes, it works! How can I set the storage permission from my app?

Comment: @Expertwannabe Check out this link for working sample app - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `settings->App Manager->Your app->Permissions`.And enable `storage` permission.Cordova file plugin not fully Support runntime permission of android.You can change the plugin to support it.You can check this reference to know how you can approach [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). At first make sure `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` is there in Android Manifest file.

Comment: Yes, I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in my Manifest file. and I confirmed it works on Android V.5.

Comment: ok it will work in lower version than android 6.In android 6 one feature is added as Runtime Permission.For this if permission is not there you should show a popup to user to enable the permission

Comment: I see, thank you so much. Now I'm searching how I can add the requesting runtime permission. If you have any advise, please let me know. thank you again!

Comment: Welcum..go for it.Then you can learn.If you will not able to do let me know I will help you